# How to get the request header with restassured

Tags: java, rest-assured, cucumber-java

I am trying to get the request header before sending the request. Is there an easy way to get the request header directly? Tried something like `requestSpecification.log().all()` but it will print all the details. Or should I use something like this `"RequestLoggingFilter"`?

Comment: Could you please add example to demonstrate what you want? Your question confused me. Is there anything in request header you want to save or you just want to print exactly header you want?

Answer (score 2):

You can use that by casting your request specification to `FilterableRequestSpecification`.

Do not forget to check if it implements mentioned interface.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RequestSpecification header = RestAssured
            .given()
            .header("myHeader", "myValue")
            .header("myHeader2", "myValue2");
    if(header instanceof FilterableRequestSpecification){
        FilterableRequestSpecification spec = (FilterableRequestSpecification)header;
        System.out.println(spec.getHeaders());
    }
}
```

Type check is required because while `RestAssured.given()` returns `RequestSpecification` the only implementation in default package also implements `RequestSpecification` but in some kinda heavy-customized cases it might not be true..

However given approach will likely work in 99.99% of cases.